# mongodb - Filter object and child array in same query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data structure saved in a mongodb collectionn named `images`

```
[
    {
        folder: 'cats',
        files: [
            {filename: 'redCat.jpg', _id: 1},
            {filename: 'blueCat.jpg', _id: 2},
            {filename: 'yellowCat.jpg', _id: 3},
        ]
    },{
        folder: 'dogs',
        files: [
            {filename: 'redDog.jpg', _id: 4},
            {filename: 'blueDog.jpg', _id: 5},
            {filename: 'yellowDog.jpg', _id: 6},
        ]
    },{
       ...
    }
]
```

I need to extract the `id` of a particular image, given the folder and the filename.
I'm able to get all the images in a particular folder

```
db.images.find({folder:"cats"}, {files:1})
```

but I don't know how to filter out the `files` array in the same query, in order to get the `blueCat.jpg` image id. If possible I'd avoid two sequential queries.

I tried the following query

```
db.images.find({folder:"cats", "files.filename":"blueCat.jpg"})
```

but what I get is, again, the whole file list in the cats folder. What I'm triyng to get is something like:

```
{filename: 'blueCat.jpg', _id: 2}
```

Any hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: `db.images.find({"folder":"cats","files.filename":"blueCat.jpg"}, {'files.$":1})` might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
db.images.find({"folder":"cats","files.filename":"blueCat.jpg"}, {'files.$":1})
```

give you-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576a92b47f0d626b7a74c325"), "files" : { "filename" : "blueCat.jpg", "_id" : 2 } }
```

And if you want to fetch complete list-

```
db.images.find({"folder":"cats","files.filename":"blueCat.jpg"}, {'files":1})
```

will result you-

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576a92b47f0d626b7a74c325"),
 "files" :
 { "filename" : "blueCat.jpg", "_id" : 2 }
 {"filename" : "xxxCat.jpg", "_id" : N }
 {"filename" : "yyyCat.jpg", "_id" : N }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the aggregation pipeline, and unwinding the files array, then query (`match`) the filename you are looking for.

For example:

```
db.images.aggregate([{$unwind:"$files"},{$match:{"files.filename":"blueCat.jpg"}}])
```

will give you:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576a92b47f0d626b7a74c325"), "folder" : "cats", "files" : { "filename" : "blueCat.jpg", "_id" : 2 } }
```

You can further refine the output document by using `project`.  Eg:

```
db.images.aggregate([{$unwind:"$files"},{$match:{"files.filename":"blueCat.jpg"}},{$project:{"files.filename":1, "files._id":1}}])
```

will return:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576a92b47f0d626b7a74c325"), "files" : { "filename" : "blueCat.jpg", "_id" : 2 } }
```

Comment: What if both cats and dogs folder contain an image with the same name?

Comment: You would get two documents returned.